# CSS Issue - active state for navigation item

Tags: css, inheritance, navigation

On the following test site (http://tronitech.brettatkin.com/index.asp), I want each navigation element to have a different look when it is the active page.

I have assigned a class to the anchor element when that page is active.

When I add the CSS inline, it works (the home page for example), but when I drop it in a class it doesn't.

Here is my CSS:

```
#navigation ul li .active-link a {
    color: #326ea1;
    background-image: url(/images/nav-current.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

I think it is something with inheritance, but I'm not seeing the issue...

Thanks

Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your selector to the following

```
#navigation ul li a.active-link
```

`a .active-link` tries to match an anchor tag with a child that has class `active-link`. `a.active-link` matches anchor tags with class `active-link`.

Answer (score 1):

it's not `#navigation ul li .active-link a` but it should be `#navigation ul li a.active-link`. The first rule says link that is decendant of class `active-link` whlie second says link with a class `active-link` - which is what you've got in your markup.

In fact both selectors are way too long.

Comment: How should they be shorter?  Thanks

Comment: "#navigation a" and "#navigation .active-link" (in that order) is sufficient.

Comment: I don't need the a. in front of the .active-link?

Comment: Provided you save the order of declarations (as you reduce specificity), you don't need the "a".